# Datagridview cellcontentclick event not getting time to complete

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, I have an edit `Button` associated with each row.

On `CellContentClick` event I am dynamically deleting and creating number of `textbox` and `Label` controls in my `TableLayoutPanel`

This dynamic deletion and creation of control is taking some time also flickering (well thats not a big issuse).

But the problem is if someone continuously keep clicking on edit `buttons` of various rows after some time the whole `TableLayoutPanel` is a complete mess.

Accordng to me this is happening coz my `CellContentClick` event is not geting time to complete and before the event get complete one click the edit `button` of some other row. 
And I am unable to handle this situation

The handler code is here:

```
Private Sub gdXMLDOc1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gdXMLDOc1.CellContentClick
    Try
        If lockThis = False Then
            lockThis = True

            If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

                intPreviousRowIndex = intSelectedRowIndex
                intSelectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex

                gdXMLDOc1.Rows(intSelectedRowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue

                If intPreviousRowIndex <> -1 And intPreviousRowIndex <> intSelectedRowIndex Then

                    arrQuestion(intPreviousRowIndex).questionText = Replace(txtQText_New.Text, """", "\""")
                    arrQuestion(intPreviousRowIndex).choice = Replace(txtOpt1_New.Text, """", "\""")

                    For i As Integer = 0 To arrQuestion(intPreviousRowIndex).cText_eng.Length - 1

                        arrQuestion(intPreviousRowIndex).cText(i).line = Replace(TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(2, i + 3).Text, """", "\""")

                    Next

                    For i = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1 To 3 Step -1
                        TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1
                        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, i))
                        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(1, i))
                        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(2, i))
                    Next

                End If

                TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4

                txtQText.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).questionText_eng
                txtOpt1.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).choice_eng
                txtQText_New.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).questionText
                txtOpt1_New.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).choice
                TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1
                Dim intRowIndex As Integer = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount

                For i As Integer = 0 To arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).cText_eng.Length - 1

                    Dim lbl As Label = New Label()
                    lbl.AutoSize = True
                    lbl.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
                    lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 36)
                    lbl.TabIndex = 5
                    lbl.Text = "Line" + arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).cText_eng(i).lineId.ToString

                    Dim TxtBox1 As dynamicTextBox = New dynamicTextBox()
                    TxtBox1.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).cText_eng(i).line

                    Dim TxtBox2 As TextBox = New TextBox()
                    TxtBox2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Mangal", 13.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
                    TxtBox2.MaxLength = 50000
                    TxtBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(600, 37)
                    TxtBox2.TabIndex = 16
                    TxtBox2.Text = arrQuestion(intSelectedRowIndex).cText(i).line

                    TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount + 1

                    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, intRowIndex)
                    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(TxtBox1, 1, intRowIndex)
                    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(TxtBox2, 2, intRowIndex)


                    intRowIndex = TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount
                Next

            End If
            lockThis = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() functions to help with the flickering. For the other part, it's hard to be sure without any code. One possibility is if you use Appliation.DoEvents() anywhere. That can cause problems where one thread calls your method before a prior instance has completed, which can create the kind of results you describe.

Comment: hi thanx . i have added the code can u please tell me where to use suspenlayout() and resumelayout().

Comment: You wrap them round the code that creates / moves / m,esses about with the UI. So in you cell contentclick SuspendLayout(); try{do UI stuff}finally{ResumeLayout();}

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing this

Disable the button while the code in the event handler is running

Add a boolean property, test if true, set it to true, do your stuff set it to false.

Have alook to see if you can queue of the "edit request" and do teh bulk of teh work in the background.

2nd one would be my choice, for a quick win.

And ....

"keep clicking on edit buttons of various rows after "

Do all your edit buttons have the same handler?

Given you've done

```
if (!_inhibit)
{
  try
  {
    _inhibit = true;
    // mess with template
  }
  finally
  {
    _inhibit = false;
  }
}
```

Just don't see how that can go wrong.  if you put a debug `_inhibit = true`, it should never get there unless the handler code has finished. Given that's true, what you think is wrong isn't.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It is a private member of the class isn't it, not a local in the method?

Comment: Nope you'd have noticed that. Just noticed somthing in your question though. Editing mine

Comment: i have added the code u can see and yes all edit buttons have the same handler. edit buttons are actually edit column of datagridview .

Comment: I don't get why it's not working then, very little to go wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

use the cell clickevent instead like this

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

the cell content click works when the user clicks on the text in the table creating a confusing user experience